# Como transformar uma coluna no tipo porcentagem? Python

Tags: python, pandas, tipagem, dataframe, porcentagem

Criei uma lista vazia chamada table[]

Em outra variável 'linha' recebo os dados e faço um split pra separar todos os dados, daí vira uma lista assim =

['/dev/', '425G', '347G', 56, '87%', '/', 'Nome da Central']

Segue código para testar:

```
table = []
central = 'Teste'
linha = '/dev/sda3       982G   27G  906G   3% /'

linha = linha.split()
linha.append(central)

table.append(linha)
```

Faço um table.append(linha) pra no final usar essa lista pra fazer o excel.

Agora segue o tratamento da planilha

```
import time
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=['Armazenamento', 'Tamanho', 'Usado', 'Disponível G', 'Uso %', 'ND', 'Central'])

#Deletar a sexta coluna
df = df.drop(columns=['ND'])
#df['Uso%'].astype(float) - tentativa de mudar o tipo mal sucedida

#criando o excel
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f'relatorioSDB_{timestr}.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
print(f'relatorioSDB_{timestr}.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Armazenamento Disco', index=False, header=True)
writer.save()
```

A questão é que, quando eu abro esse excel ele da um erro falando que deveria ser um número e está como texto... sei que é só clicar em converter em número que resolve, mas gostaria que esse erro não aparecesse.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei transformar esse index da lista em int ou float mas ele não aceita pcausa do caractere '%'

O que eu posso fazer - ou no tratamento do excel ou na tipação dele - pra ele ficar como porcentagem e não aparecer esse erro no excel?

Comment: Você pode eliminar o % antes de salvar como planilha. Uma maneira seria `df["Uso %"] = df["Uso %"].str.replace("%", "")`.

Comment: @sourcream 
Sim, eu consegui fzr isso, só queria saber mesmo se existia um tipo pra porcentagem, já q no excel os números em porcentagem são tipados como número. 
Quando eu tentei converter o object '22%' pra número ele não aceita pcausa do caractere..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Note o seguinte: se você já está indicando no cabeçalho da coluna que os valores serão exibidos em porcentagem (Uso %), não há porque também colocar o mesmo símbolo de porcentagem junto com cada valor.

Veja que ao rodar o comando `df.info()`, retornará o seguinte:

```
`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column         Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------         --------------  ----- 
 0   Armazenamento  1 non-null      object
 1   Tamanho        1 non-null      object
 2   Usado          1 non-null      object
 3   Disponível G   1 non-null      object
 4   Uso %          1 non-null      object
 5   ND             1 non-null      object
 6   Central        1 non-null      object
dtypes: object(7)
memory usage: 184.0+ bytes`
```

Observe que todas as colunas são do tipo objeto. Bom, não sei se estou certo, é apenas meu palpite, pois não testei a conversão para o Excel.

Converta a coluna `Uso %` para o tipo numérico:

`df['Uso %'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Uso %'])`

Verificando novamente com o `df.info()` verá que a coluna, em questão, foi convertida para o tipo float64. Veja se dá certo.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ao tentar converter recebo essa resposta:
Unable to parse string "3%"
Pelo que procurei na documentação, tudo que tem a ver com porcentagem ele utiliza 0.03 ao invés de 3%...